# Export / Import JFrameForm from Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.0 and I created a simple GUI using the JFrameForm drag/drop feature. How can I export it and re-import to Netbeans with all the same code-lock / JFrame navigation?

Answer (score 0):

What is code-lock?

How about using the following actions in the menu?

- `Menu->File->Export Project->To ZIP...`
- `Menu->File->Import Project->From ZIP...`

Tested with NetBeans 7.4

Comment: Sorry I don't know the technical term for it, but when you use the JFrameForm tool, certain code is greyed out and 'locked' for editing. I cannot use a zip file since my company will not allow that through its security policies. I just need a way to export the jFrameForm to and from a machine without zipping it up.

Comment: a) Those protected region contain generated code from the GUI designer. Do not change this code (in an external editor), else you cannot change the form anymore using the GUI designer.

b)  I just need a way to export the jFrameForm to and from a machine without zipping it up. –> Go to the filesystem where the file is located and do whatever you want with this file. Do not forget the .form file